# check if digit is at same position in two different numbers

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements, nested-loops

Q)write a program to check at which position digits are same and print the position at which they are same.

for example, if n1=1234453 and n2=2444853 print
Same at 1's position

Same at 10th position

Same at 1000th position

how to fix this so it works? it display's 3th position instead of 100th?

```
n1=int(input())
n2=int(input())
ns1=str(n1)
ns2=str(n2)
l1=len(ns1)
for x in ns1:
    for y in ns2:
        if x==y:
            if int(ns1.index(x))==int(ns2.index(y)):
                print("Same at %dth position"%(ns1.index(x)))
            else:
                print("No digits are same")
        else:
            print("No digits are same")
```

Comment: You haven't properly closed the parens in the if block.

Comment: @SayandipDutta just changed it

Comment: If you have a traceback, please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @quamrana no error. it was there before but sayandip pointed it out. right now it's just not showing me the correct output

Comment: Your code as posted has a typo on the first `print(...` line.

Comment: @quamrana i thought i edited it already  i must have forgotten to click save. thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `zip`, `enumerate` and powers of `10`:

```
ns1 = "1234453"
ns2 = "2444853"

found = False
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(ns1[::-1], ns2[::-1])):
    if x == y:
         found = True
         print(f"Same at {10**i}th position")
    # no else here!! just because of a mismatch at the first digit
    # does not mean there aren't any matches later
if not found:
    print("No digits are same")

# Same at 1th position
# Same at 10th position
# Same at 1000th position
```

Your nested loops are doing way too much work, looping through the entire second string for each char in the first. `zip` is much more efficient, just doing a pair-wise (parallel) iteration of both (reversed) strings.

Some docs:

- [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)
- [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- slice notation: [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html), [extensive thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: how do zip and enumerate work? and is the [::-1] still an way of indexing or something else?

Comment: I added links to the relevant parts of the documentation. The `[::-1]` is slice notation and just a concise way of reversing strings, lists, etc.

Comment: okayy thank you sm!